# Unable to set paper size in SSRS (it always remain Letter)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am making a report in SSRS (SQL Server 2012). The main report has many sub reports under it. All main and sub reports have the following properties:

Orientation: Landscape
Margins: Custom
Paper Size: A4

When I export the report in Word, it always shows Paper Size as "Letter" and I have to change it to "A4" in it. Orientation and Margins are correctly exported. What's the problem with Paper Size? Why doesn't it export correct Paper Size as defined in SSRS which is "A4" and always resort to "Letter"?

**EDIT**

I just created a new basic test report with one Tablix in it. It is also showing same behavior i.e. even though I have set Paper Size to A4 when I export the report in Word, it changes to "Letter".

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you find any workaround?

Comment: I found out that SSRS doesn't save Paper Size in rdl files. If you open RDL file in notepad and search for let's say PageHeight then you will find it. But you won't find Paper Size hence when you export to Word, paper size is not exported.